# View is not rendering

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

Below is my angular code

```
MDIApp.controller("loginCtrl", function ($scope, $http,$location,$sce) { 
        $scope.toTrustedHTML = function (html) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
        }

        $scope.getLogin = function (proCode) {
            alert("Code " + proCode);
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/Home/getProviderLogin?id=' + proCode,
            }).
            success(function (data) {
                debugger;
                $scope.ProviderLogin = data;
                $scope.ProviderLoginPop = true;
                //$location.path = '~/WelcomePage.cshtml';
                $http.post("/Home/WelcomePage", { postId: id });
            });

        }
    });
```

and Below is my controller code

```
public ActionResult getProviderLogin(string id)
        {
            var providercode = objHomeRepo.getLogin(id);
            //return View("WelcomePage");
            return RedirectToAction("WelcomePage", "Home");

        }
```

I am trying to call welcomepage view but its not rendering....

Comment: `$http` is async request so do you think `RedirectToAction` will work?

Comment: i am new in angular please suggest

Comment: i tried using return view("WelcomePage"); same problem

Answer (score 1):

Redirection will not work in ajax post. You can return the target url in your controller and redirect it manually in the javascript code.

In you controller, return your url

```
return Json(Url.Action("WelcomePage", "Home"));
```

In your javascript code  use

```
$location.path('url')
```

or

```
window.location.href = url;
```